# Write LOG on database once the $_SESSION expires

Tags: php, session, logout

On my `database` I have a table called `LOG` where I write a row each time a user log-in successfully.

The same thing happens when a user `log-out`, but if the log-out isn't done by the page `logout.php` then once `$_SESSION` expires, no log will be written on the `database`.

How to avoid that or automatically write a `LOG` each time the `$_SESSION` expires?

Comment: you can't, you could run a cron job to fill in data for those who don't go through logout.php. or most of us just leave blanks and understand what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally rather painful to do this: PHP simply doesn't really expose session expiry in any meaningful way.

However, typically PHP installs a cron job to expire the sessions (in my Linux server it is `/etc/cron.d/php5`): no idea how you'd do it but you might modify the equivalent script on your system to open the log files that are about to be deleted, and then send their identities to your log database.

Comment: I think I will avoid to write a Logout LOG!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own [session save handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). You want to deal with this in the destroy and GC methods of the save handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the session expiring is handled all on the browser, it doesn't involve the server at all, so there's no way for the session expiring to communicate back to the server and cause a write to the database.

That said, there are ways to back into what you're looking for.  If you know how long the cookie will live on the client browser, and you log the last site access that refreshes the start time, you can run a check on all accesses older than the timeout.

If the session lives for the browser session, you're SOL.  Just log access times and infer the rest.

Comment: well not strictly true, sessions are server side, not client side.

Comment: The session *data* is server side.  The session cookie (being a cookie) is client side.  I assumed we were talking about the cookie, rather than the lifetime of the data itself on the server, but I could have been mistaken.  If you're talking about the expiration of the data, then you can get access to the timeout by looking at the ini value for session.gc_maxlifetime, and back into it that way... just be aware that you should be able to "resurrect" the login if it hasn't been garbage collected yet.

Comment: well sessions can exist with out cookies, so i would never infer the existence of a cookie when a session exists

Comment: Using sessions without cookies is a security hole, I assume conscientious developers aren't doing it unless they've specified that they are.

Comment: explain how its any more insure than a cookie which is also editable by the user and transmitted by the same protocol as the web page.

Comment: People copy URLs from the address bar and post them all over the internet.  You're dramatically widening the attack vector when people are spreading session IDs around publicly in the course of normal behavior.  That doesn't happen with cookies.